# some simple coding in python, don't know what to do

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to do something like this:

```
for i in range(999999999999999):
     print ("sending messages no." + i)
```

but just don't know the proper way to do it since it doesn't work like this.

Comment: Did you read the error message you got? It's incredibly self explanatory.

Comment: Check the error message. If its still unclear,  post it s well, but it shsould be easy.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your value *i* is an integer and the print-function takes a string as parameter. Therefore you need to cast your variable using the str() function.

Your code should look like this:

`for i in range(999999999999999):
     print ("sending messages no." + str(i))`

Now, I encourage people to learn Python and so I am glad to help you out but next time, if you get a "*TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects*" maybe you should first check with Google (or any other place) what this error means, since it actually tells you that i is an integer and it cannot convert that to a string.

Cheers